# How to disable busy Indicator on sap.m.Table?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a `sap.m.Table`, and I am performing refresh on it. However during the duration in which data is fetched, the Table becomes inactive, which is not an outcome that is required.

I tried setting `enableBusyIndicator="false"`, but all it does is not show the busy indicator, however the table still becomes inactive on that duration.

```
<Table id="myTableId" inset="false" growing="true"
    items="{path: 'model>/entityset',sorter: {path: 'someProperty', descending: true}, filters: []}" mode="MultiSelect"
    selectionChange="onRowChange" updateFinished="updatingCount" enableBusyIndicator="false">
```

I can also see that there is a method called `setBusyIndicatorDelay`, however even if I pass `1000000` into it, it still behaves the same.

Comment: are you fetching asynchronously?

Comment: Please try calling setBusy(false).

Comment: I have tried calling setBusy(false), but the animation for refreshing the data still appears.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller declare this callback for event **updateFinished**:

```
updatingCount: function(oEvent){
   oEvent.getSource().setBusy(false);
}
```

Here is what we do here - get source of the event wich is our sap.m.Table instance, then we call method **setBusy** on the Source to hide the busy indicator.

You can also bind some model property (for example local utility **JSONModel** of your app) for a **busy** property of the **sap.m.Table** in **XML view**:

```
<Table id="myTableId" 
    inset="false"
    growing="true"
    mode="MultiSelect"
    selectionChange="onRowChange"
    updateFinished="updatingCount"
    enableBusyIndicator="false"
    busy="{LocalJSONModel>/isTableBusy}"
    items="{
        path: 'model>/entityset',
        sorter: {
            path: 'someProperty',
            descending: true}, 
        filters: []}">
```

And then change this local **JSONModel** property to hide busy indicator like this:

```
updatingCount: function(oEvent){
    oEvent.getSource().getModel('LocalJSONModel').setProperty('/isTableBusy', false);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried both of these approaches already, and I can still see the animation whenever the data is updated in table.

Comment: Hi, do you have a JSBin example?